# Can't get Wordpress installation from backup working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am trying to install a backup based off of GetFlywheel.com backup, they give wp-content and a .sql file.

I installed vanilla Wordpress, dropped the tables, imported the sql file, and replaced the wp-content folder, and now when I try and access the installation I receive a litany of errors. What's going on?

```
Notice: force_ssl_login is deprecated since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3658

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; BVHttpClient has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-site-migrate/bv_http_client.php on line 3

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; BlogVault has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-site-migrate/bv_class.php on line 3

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; BVDynamicBackup has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-site-migrate/bv_dynamic_backup.php on line 3

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; BVSecurity has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-site-migrate/bv_security.php on line 3

Notice: force_ssl_login is deprecated since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3658

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'remove_admin_bar' not found or invalid function name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; AboutMeWidget has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/widgets/widget-about.php on line 1

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; AdsenseWidget has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/widgets/widget-adsense.php on line 1

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; AdvWidget has a deprecated constructor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/widgets/widget-ads.php on line 1

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in AboutMeWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in AdsenseWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in AdvWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718

Notice: force_ssl_login is deprecated since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3658

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php:3658) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/accesspress-social-login-lite/accesspress-social-login-lite.php on line 182

Notice: force_ssl_login is deprecated since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3658

Notice: force_ssl_login is deprecated since version 4.4! Use force_ssl_admin() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3658

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 8652

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 8652

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php:3658) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1167
```

Note: If WP_DEBUG is set to false, I receive an error that I can't connect to the server at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version of WP you used is out of sync with the version used by your database.  I would try dropping your wp-content directory into an up-to-date version of WP and see if that helps.

Comment: If anything, the database is using an older version of WP than the vanilla installation I setup. Would that make sense from what you see in the logs?

Comment: Not particularly, as the errors thrown were all in the code and not SQL errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by upgrading WP.

Comment: It looks like I'm running the latest version of Wordpress, so I'm guessing I should install a previous version of wordpress to make it suitable with the DB. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I had a previous version of WP in my machine. If you have the latest version installed i can't help you